# LinkedResource in a css

Tags: c#, css, email, smtp, embedded-resource

I am trying to send an email with HTML body.
I have found many examples, on this site and elsewhere that explain very well how to use the [LinkedResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.linkedresource.aspx) class for an HTML TAG of type `IMG`.

In my case I have the following code:

```
<table id="page" style="border: 2px solid #ff0000; ">
    <tr>
        [...]
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the following stylesheet:

```
    #page {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: url(https://www.example.com/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

And here is the code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString( plainTextMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain" );
mail.AlternateViews.Add( plainView );
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString( htmlTextMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html" );
mail.AlternateViews.Add( htmlView ); 
mail.Body = htmlTextMessage;  
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.To.Add( new MailAddress( customer.Email, customer.FullName ) );
mail.From = new MailAddress( "noreply@example.com", "My Web site" );

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send( mail );
```

How can I use the LinkedResource class to embed the background image?

Comment: It seems your question should be tagged with css, not C#; else, add what you've tried in C# to get LInkedResource to work (which hasn't).

Comment: Right. I have edited the question to add the code and approved the edit. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that your CSS is being stripped from email body, which almost all mail providers do, only inline CSS works on most of them. Once you end writing your CSS, inline it using a CSS Inliner Tool, like this one: http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html

Comment: I second using inline CSS for email generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted will display a background image, depending on what email client is looking at the email. Outlook 2007-2010 will not, nor will Gmail or Yahoo. Apple devices will.

Comments on your question suggest to move things inline, which will help improve the number of clients. Though, to satisfy your question, I'm not sure if LinkedResource is something you can use for this purpose, but you might want to try using Bulletproof Backgrounds: https://backgrounds.cm

This will generate the HTML code needed to ensure it works in the most email clients.